# Difference between 商売 and 事業

Tags: word-choice

I know that 商売 and 事業 both mean business but I'm failing to understand the distinction. There is a further word, 企業 but I get the impression that is for big corporations. I'm guessing the likes of Amazon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

事業 refers to any business activity, regardless of its size, but it is most commonly associated with modern commercial activities involving a large number of people. It's also a legal term. It also includes public projects such as the construction of highways and the development of space technology (cf. 公共事業). The sense of making money is not necessarily strong, and the focus is on the activity/project (or "mission") itself.

商売 is a word that does not usually appear in law. It is primarily associated with a relatively small business where an individual or a small group makes money by directly buying and selling goods. The first thing I imagine when I hear 商売 is a merchant selling groceries in a store or on the street. It's not impossible to use 商売 to describe businesses such as programming, but the underlying image is directly selling something on a small scale, satisfying customers, and making a living with it.

For example, the website of a company typically has a 事業内容 ("our business/mission") section. This is not 商売内容 because 商売 is associated with moneymaking and it's not a suitable word in a modern formal business setting, anyway.

企業 (typically translated as "company") is a type of organization, not a type of activity.